# Getting data out of a JSON API with PHP

Tags: php, json

Im having trouble extracting data from a API, i would like to use for a school project..

[The link to the API i here](http://www.odaa.dk/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=2a82a145-0195-4081-a13c-b0e587e9b89c)
Or here's a sample of the API output

```
{
    "help": "http://www.odaa.dk/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_search",
    "success": true,
    "result": {
        "resource_id": "2a82a145-0195-4081-a13c-b0e587e9b89c",
        "fields": [
            {
                "type": "int4",
                "id": "_id"
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "id": "date"
            },
            {
                "type": "text",
                "id": "garageCode"
            },
            {
                "type": "int4",
                "id": "totalSpaces"
            },
            {
                "type": "int4",
                "id": "vehicleCount"
            }
        ],
        "records": [
            {
                "date": "2015/11/11 03:50:07",
                "vehicleCount": 62,
                "_id": 1,
                "totalSpaces": 65,
                "garageCode": "NORREPORT"
            },
            {
                "date": "2015/11/11 03:50:07",
                "vehicleCount": 512,
                "_id": 2,
                "totalSpaces": 512,
                "garageCode": "SKOLEBAKKEN"
            },
            {
                "date": "2015/11/11 03:50:07",
                "vehicleCount": 236,
                "_id": 3,
                "totalSpaces": 1240,
                "garageCode": "SCANDCENTER"
            },
            {
                "date": "2015/11/11 03:50:07",
                "vehicleCount": 40,
                "_id": 4,
                "totalSpaces": 953,
                "garageCode": "BRUUNS"
            },
            {
                "date": "2015/11/11 03:50:07",
                "vehicleCount": 2932,
                "_id": 5,
                "totalSpaces": 142,
                "garageCode": "BUSGADEHUSET"
            },
            {
                "date": "2015/11/11 03:50:07",
                "vehicleCount": 18,
                "_id": 6,
                "totalSpaces": 383,
                "garageCode": "MAGASIN"
            },
            {
                "date": "2015/11/11 03:50:07",
                "vehicleCount": 3,
                "_id": 7,
                "totalSpaces": 210,
                "garageCode": "KALKVAERKSVEJ"
            },
            {
                "date": "2015/11/11 03:50:07",
                "vehicleCount": 255,
                "_id": 8,
                "totalSpaces": 700,
                "garageCode": "SALLING"
            },
            {
                "date": "2015/11/11 03:50:07",
                "vehicleCount": 0,
                "_id": 9,
                "totalSpaces": 0,
                "garageCode": "DOKK1"
            },
            {
                "date": "2015/11/11 03:50:07",
                "vehicleCount": 34,
                "_id": 10,
                "totalSpaces": 449,
                "garageCode": "Navitas"
            },
            {
                "date": "2015/11/11 03:50:07",
                "vehicleCount": 105,
                "_id": 11,
                "totalSpaces": 105,
                "garageCode": "NewBusgadehuset"
            },
            {
                "date": "2015/11/11 03:50:07",
                "vehicleCount": 9,
                "_id": 12,
                "totalSpaces": 319,
                "garageCode": "Urban Level 1"
            },
            {
                "date": "2015/11/11 03:50:07",
                "vehicleCount": 15,
                "_id": 13,
                "totalSpaces": 654,
                "garageCode": "Urban Level 2+3"
            }
        ],
        "_links": {
            "start": "/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=2a82a145-0195-4081-a13c-b0e587e9b89c",
            "next": "/api/action/datastore_search?offset=100&resource_id=2a82a145-0195-4081-a13c-b0e587e9b89c"
        },
        "total": 13
    }
}
```

I would like to extract the cells called "vehicleCount" and "_id", but i seems I can't figure out how to do it :(

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.odaa.dk/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=2a82a145-0195-4081-a13c-b0e587e9b89c');
$json = json_decode($json);
echo $json->fields->_id;
```

I have tried many different ways, but now loss of ideas and its 4 o'clock in the morning, so hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: You can try debugging by `var_dump($json->fields)`.

Comment: Do what Raptor suggested, but to me it looks like `$json->result->fields[0]->id` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Small note on @JosefEngelfrost comment , last key should be `->_id` not just `->id`, but I am sure you will have figured that out.

Comment: thanks @josefEngelfrost but its was $json->result->records->_id and VehicleCount is was looking for...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to extract the cells `vehicleCount` and `_id`

This is my solution for you:

```
<?php 
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.odaa.dk/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=2a82a145-0195-4081-a13c-b0e587e9b89c');
$json = json_decode($json);


foreach ($json->result->records as $val) {
  echo "_id = " .$val->_id . " vehicleCount = " . $val->vehicleCount . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$json->result->records[0]->_id
```

Comment: Not according to your original post, this should not work. Your original post has `records` as an array filled with array objects, just like @josefEngelfrost mentioned. Would be `$json->result->records[0]->_id;` according to your original post